# Grouping and summarising data (without loops)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data, and I'm trying to group the SalesType (where = Sales) by Name, and create a new row that keeps the minimum of that Group as the Value and Level1 result and the maximum value as Level2.  I don't want to keep the rest of the data.

Because the Level1 and Level2 also contains character data (that I'd like to keep for some SalesType), I'm having a trouble doing this without a whole lot of loops and filtering.

Can anyone suggest how I can change the input below:

```
input = structure(list(BusinessDate = structure(c(1678626000, 1678626000, 
1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 
1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 
1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Name = c("JANE_T", 
"JANE_T", "JANE_T", "JANE_T", "FRANK_E", "FRANK_E", "FRANK_E", 
"FRANK_E", "TOM_S", "TOM_S", "TOM_S", "TOM_S", "REG_W", "REG_W", 
"REG_W", "REG_W", "SALLY_M", "SALLY_M", "SALLY_M", "SALLY_M"), 
    Report = c("Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", 
    "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", 
    "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", 
    "Annual", "Annual", "Annual"), SalesType = c("Sales", "Sales", 
    "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", 
    "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", 
    "Promo", "Promo", "Promo", "Promo"), CustCode = c("N/A", 
    "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
    "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
    "N/A"), Currency = c("USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
    "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
    "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD"), Level1 = c("VER0.75", 
    "VER0.75", "VER1.25", "VER1.25", "VER0.75", "VER0.75", "VER1.25", 
    "VER1.25", "VER0.75", "VER0.75", "VER1.25", "VER1.25", "VER0.75", 
    "VER0.75", "VER1.25", "VER1.25", "VER0.75", "VER0.75", "VER1.25", 
    "VER1.25"), Level2 = c("PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", 
    "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", 
    "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", 
    "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00"), Value = c(12, 
    12, -12, 12, 7, 7, -4, -8, -1, 11, 13, -1, -2, -2, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

into this:

```
output = structure(list(BusinessDate = structure(c(1678626000, 1678626000, 
1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000, 1678626000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Name = c("JANE_T", 
"FRANK_E", "TOM_S", "REG_W", "SALLY_M", "SALLY_M", "SALLY_M", 
"SALLY_M"), Report = c("Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual", 
"Annual", "Annual", "Annual", "Annual"), SalesType = c("Sales", 
"Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Promo", "Promo", "Promo", "Promo"
), CustCode = c("N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", "N/A", 
"N/A"), Currency = c("USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", "USD", 
"USD", "USD"), Level1 = c("-12", "-8", "-1", "-2", "VER0.75", 
"VER0.75", "VER1.25", "VER1.25"), Level2 = c("12", "7", "13", 
"2", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00", "PAT0.50", "PAT2.00"), Value = c(-12, 
-8, -1, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = 13:20, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It is hard to imagine a proper use case for untyding the data with this weird `numeric with some character values` column. It can hardly be any helpful and could bring hell during downstream analyses. Please tell the goals of such transformations, and maybe we can help more than we would by just answering what was asked

Comment: I'd tried splitting the min and max values out to a new numeric column (min and max), but this didn't seem to solve the issue of grouping the data with out a loop.

Comment: see if the answer with `group_split > transformations on df2 > rbind` helps

Answer (score 1):

It may be a better approach to `split` the original data.frame into a list of two data.frames and work with them separately.
If it is really necessary (I would not recommend), we can bind the two data.frames back together, but Level1 and Level2 would have to be coerced into character.

We can `split` on `SalesType` then use `modify_at` to change only the seccond data.frame with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

input %>% 
    group_split(SalesType) %>%
    modify_at(.at = 2,
              .f = ~ mutate(.x,
                           Level1 = min(Value),
                           Level2 = max(Value),
                           Value = Level1,
                           .by = Name,
                           )

<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    BusinessDate: datetime<local>
    Name        : character
    Report      : character
    SalesType   : character
    CustCode    : character
    Currency    : character
    Level1      : character
    Level2      : character
    Value       : double
  >
>[2]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  BusinessDate        Name    Report SalesType CustCode Currency Level1  Level2  Value
  <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER0.75 PAT0.50     1
2 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER0.75 PAT2.00     1
3 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER1.25 PAT0.50     1
4 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER1.25 PAT2.00     1

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  BusinessDate        Name    Report SalesType CustCode Currency Level1 Level2 Value
  <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 2023-03-12 10:00:00 JANE_T  Annual Sales     N/A      USD         -12     12   -12
2 2023-03-12 10:00:00 FRANK_E Annual Sales     N/A      USD          -8      7    -8
3 2023-03-12 10:00:00 TOM_S   Annual Sales     N/A      USD          -1     13    -1
4 2023-03-12 10:00:00 REG_W   Annual Sales     N/A      USD          -2      2    -2
```

For binding the data.frames back together (not recommended):

```
#pipe the end of the last answer into
    ... %>% 
    rev() %>% 
    do.call(rbind.data.frame, .)

# A tibble: 8 × 9
  BusinessDate        Name    Report SalesType CustCode Currency Level1  Level2  Value
  <dttm>              <chr>   <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 2023-03-12 10:00:00 JANE_T  Annual Sales     N/A      USD      -12     12        -12
2 2023-03-12 10:00:00 FRANK_E Annual Sales     N/A      USD      -8      7          -8
3 2023-03-12 10:00:00 TOM_S   Annual Sales     N/A      USD      -1      13         -1
4 2023-03-12 10:00:00 REG_W   Annual Sales     N/A      USD      -2      2          -2
5 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER0.75 PAT0.50     1
6 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER0.75 PAT2.00     1
7 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER1.25 PAT0.50     1
8 2023-03-12 10:00:00 SALLY_M Annual Promo     N/A      USD      VER1.25 PAT2.00     1
```

Comment: I get the same issue as when I tried it:   "Can't convert `value$Level1` <double> to match type of `Level1` <character>."  Would it be easier to instead create new <double> columns called Min and Max and keep the results as numeric?

Comment: The easier, safer, and best on the long run would be to keep this two dataframes in a list without the final re-merge, as I said before

Comment: It is just not practical to have two different types of data hackily merged into a single column

Comment: Please search `tidy data principles` on Google to find some references on this